# How to import auto from enum in python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, enums, compatibility

I'm using an old code based in python 2.7 (Can't change this, unfortunately). I have to introduce a new feature from a piece of code based in python 3.6. This piece of code would work except because it uses the package enum, which is, as far as I know, no longer maintained. So:

`from enum import Enum, auto`  (Doesn't work python 2.7)

Because I think "auto" was not defined in python 2.7. Is it possible to make that line working?  or at least install/ import "enum.auto" or something with the same functionality?

Comment: The `enum` package doesn't exist in Python 2.7 at all anyway.

Comment: @AKX Does if you install it.

Comment: `import enum;
enum.auto = ...; import other_package_that_uses_enum` should work...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a couple choices:

- use `aenum`<sup>1</sup> instead
- copy/create your own `auto()` and stuff it into `enum`

---

*Using `aenum` is a two-step process*:

- `pip install aenum`
- change `from enum` to `from aenum`

---

*Creating/copying an `auto` and stuffing it into `enum`*:

```
import enum
from itertools import count

def auto(it=count()):
  return next(it)

enum.auto = auto
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Disclosure:  I am the author of the [Python stdlib `Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), the [`enum34` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), and the [Advanced Enumeration (`aenum`)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)  library.

Comment: Many thanks for the complete reply :) that is more than enough to solve my problem.

Answer (score 2):

This might work in a pinch:

```
from itertools import count

def auto(it=count()):
    return it.next()
```

I haven't tested it, though.

Comment: Note: This will be pretty similar if `auto` is only used in a single `enum`. It would produce slightly different behaviors if used across multiple `enum`s. Also, minor nitpick, but I'd try to stick to portable constructs in case you need to use this on Py3 as well to maintain cross-version compatibility, replacing `it.next()` (Py2 only) with `next(it)` (works on both).

Comment: Yup, this is definitely only a stop-gap solution. I didn't bother making it Py3 compatible because people should really use the actual `auto` if they have access to it.

Comment: Thanks for this solution too :), was the first, is super easy and it can make the work for some cases too.